# Replace string with Characters in Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace this string:

```
var img = "<img class='messages-emoji' src='js/message/emoji/thumbsup.gif'>" ;
```

with this:

> (smile)

Here's what I tried:

```
var new = img.replace("<img class='messages-emoji' src='js/message/emoji/thumbsup.gif'>", "(smile)");
```

I need to replace this in **Regex Javascript**

Comment: _"I cannot use this standard replace code since it contains escape characters."_ Wait what? What escape characters?

Comment: The only issue I see is the fact you're trying use `new` as variable name. Also, please don't add tags to the title.

Comment: @Cerbrus Pardon me. I edited the question. I need to write it in Regex

Comment: Why do you need a Regex there? What do you mean with _"in regex"_?

Comment: Thats my requirement mate :) I'd like to know the Regex version @Cerbrus

Comment: ___Why___ do you need a regex? Are there parts of the source string that aren't constant? What do you have in mind?

Comment: I need to learn how to code that in Regex, thats why. The JS replace works fine (Y) @Cerbrus

Comment: Then I'd suggest following a JS regex tutorial, instead of asking for regexes with use cases where regexes really don't make sense to use.

Comment: Yes I understand. But I asked a simple question and at the same time another guy *actually* helped me clarify my doubts. I guess thats why we are all here in the first place. Thanks anyway :) @Sheepy

Comment: @Earthling Cerbrus was trying to help you better by making you think - and realise - that you should learn regex on regex problems.  *Politely.*  The biggest pitfall of regex is using it to solve problems that should not be solved by regex.  Try lookup this quote - `Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.`  I agree this should be the first lesson we learn on regex.

Comment: @Earthling: I'm trying to tell you to look for some proper regex tutorials, instead of using regexes in illogical scenarios like this. I'm not giving you an answer to your question, instead I'm trying to make you understand when _not_ to use regexes. That's helping.

Comment: Alrighty then. I shall get to it. Thanks @Cerbrus

Comment: Gotcha. I will take that advise @Sheepy

Comment: This site: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html Offers quite a lot of info about regexes. It's more like an api than an tutorial, but anything you want to know is in there.

Comment: So Regex is overkill for something like a 'replace'? Okay I will switch to using JS then. Going through that site now @Cerbrus

Comment: That depends. If the "target" of the replacement is a constant string, you don't need a regex. However, if you're looking to replace something like _"all numbers"_ in a string with something else, then regexes are the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>I think the issue is that you are using the reserved word `new` as your variable name. I suggest changing to something different:</s>

```
var newImg = img.replace("<img class='messages-emoji' src='js/message/emoji/thumbsup.gif'>", "(smile)");
```

As others have pointed out, regex doesn't make sense for this use case, a simple string replace is better for multiple reasons.

Regex would generally be used when you want to replace a string with variable parts, but you know some (pattern) of the source string. An example in your case would be if the `src` attribute could be anything, but you knew the tag was always going to have the `messages-emoji` class (Though even in this case, there are better ways to achieve this).

That said, I'll keep my answer in place as it does seem to have solved your problem.

---

There a number of things wrong here:

- The `new` keyword is a reserved word in JavaScript, you need to choose a different name for your variable here otherwise you will get a syntax error.
- Your string contains `/` characters, which is used to denote a literal regular expression in JavaScript. You need to escape each of these with the `\` character.

```
var img = "<img class='messages-emoji' src='js/message/emoji/thumbsup.gif'>";
var regex = /<img class='messages-emoji' src='js\/message\/emoji\/thumbsup.gif'>/;

var newImg = img.replace(regex, "(smile)");
```

Comment: How can I write this in Regex?

Comment: Updated my answer to use regex

Comment: @Earthling No problem. I have updated my answer to explain a little *why* people were (rightly so) trying to dissuade you from using regular expressions. I appreciate you're trying to learn how to use the language feature by way of example, but if this were a real-world problem, there are much better solutions than regex in this instance.

Comment: I understood that regex isn't the 'go-to' solution for this kinda problem after a bit of research I did just now. Thanks anyway for the answer and the detailed information. Helped a lot! Thanks man!